# Expand <p> in the same <div> as <button>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="row featurette">
   <div class="col-md-5">
      <img class="featurette-image img-responsive" src="img/serv_thumb.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" title="916 x 458">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-7">
      <h2 class="featurette-heading">News Story Uno 
          <span class="text-muted"></span>     
      </h2>
      <p class="sub">He aquí una rápida veraniego de la noticia, ya que el promedio de atención de un americano hoy es de alrededor de 5 segundos. Pero si lo desea, haga clic aquí para leer más!</p>
      <button class="btn-default btn-sm btn-marketing">Expand Story</button>
      <p class="hidden">Estamos agregando constantemente a nuestra cartera de contenido de vídeo de alta calidad. Lo que encontrará aquí son ejemplos de nuestros servicios que se muestran a través de productos terminados de los clientes podía comprender. Yo, literalmente, sólo añadí esta historia para obtener la página para desplazarse. Creo seis y cincuenta y seis relatos de la página debe ser bueno, y luego tener el botón de archivo a continuación.</p>
      <p class="hidden">Yo, literalmente, sólo añadí esta historia para obtener la página para desplazarse. Creo seis y cincuenta y seis relatos de la página debe ser bueno, y luego tener el botón de archivo a continuación. Estamos agregando constantemente a nuestra cartera de contenido de vídeo de alta calidad. Lo que encontrará aquí son ejemplos de nuestros servicios que se muestran a través de productos terminados de los clientes podía comprender.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

So that's my `<div>`...pretty standard. It's an expandable news story. The paragraphs with the cals hidden are hidden on ready by the line `$(".hidden").hide(0);` in my jQuery/JS file. However, I am stumped.

How can I go about getting only the paragraphs in the same `div` as the `button` to `.slideToggle();` onClick?

Comment: You can try to make a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)**:

```
$('button.btn-default').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('p.hidden').slideToggle();
});
```

or **[.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)**:

```
$('button.btn-default').click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('p.hidden').slideToggle();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9f8fj/)**

Comment: He asked for the paragraphs in the same div as the button wouldn't you want to do `'p'` instead of `'.hidden'`? Although it looks like he just asked incorrectly for what he actually wanted.

Comment: I used that, and added the `console.log();` function to confirm it's being registered. It prints my line to the console, but doesn't do anything to the page.

Comment: @KevinHaube I don't get what you means. Did you check my demo?

Comment: @Felix I didn't see the `nextAll()` one before. It works now. Thank you!

Comment: Also, the ".hidden" class was predefined by Bootstrap with `display: none;` ... Now I just feel dumb!