# How to slide down a partial image to reveal full image

Tags: php, html, expand

I'm trying to do like on Twitter (with the Expand button) by showing a partial preview of an image in a Div to with an "expand" to click to slide down and reveal the whole image within that div.

I'm not sure how to achieve this. The scripts that I find never include the slide down effect on an already semi-visible image to reveal it fully.

The only script that is similar to this is this ([Expand <p> in the same <div> as <button>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395188/expand-p-in-the-same-div-as-button)) but it doesn't work with images like that twitter script marvellously does and nobody seems to have written anything on how to do this on the web

UPDATE:

I think this might work for me: http://spoonfedproject.com/jquery/jquery-slide-with-minimum-height/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this fancybox. Checkout the below link.

http://fancybox.net/

Comment: Thanks but its not what I'm looking for. I've updated my question to make it clearer tho!